# How to do comments page and filtering them by time

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to do a comments page (pure javascript no Jquery) and have got to the point where I've been able to get it to appear after I press the submit button but when I refresh the page it all goes away.

Also I'm trying to make a dropdown list that helps me filter the comments that were entered like 5 minutes ago/10 minutes ago but I have no idea how to start. A fully working solution might be the best since I'll be able to look through and understand the code but literally any help is appreciated. Thank you

The jsfiddle if that helps  https://jsfiddle.net/ybqk9rnb/

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CommentsPage.css'>
<script>

var arrayofcomments = []
var listofcomments = []
var i = 0
function action(){
    var comment = document.getElementById('header').value;
    arrayofcomments.push(comment);
    localStorage.setItem('commentstorag',arrayofcomments);
    document.getElementById('header').value = " ";
    var username = 'username:'
    var para = document.createElement('P');
    para.innerHTML= username + arrayofcomments[i] + '<br>';
    listofcomments.push(para);
    document.getElementById('hello').appendChild(para);
    var bio = document.getElementById('hello').querySelector('*');
    i = i + 1 
    localstorage.setItem('commentstorage',bio);
}


function sol(){
    var nano = document.getElementById('hello')
    nano = localStorage.getItem('commentstorag')
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul> 
 <li><a href='home'>Home</a></li>
 <li class='dropdown'><a class='dropbtn'>News</a><div class='dropdown-
 content'>
    <a href='CommentsPage.html'>User Comments</a>
    <a href='OfficialNews.html'>Official News</a>
    </div>
    </li>
 <li class='dropdown'><a class='dropbtn'>Card</a><div class='dropdown-
 content'>
    <a href='topup'>Top Up</a>
    <a href='balancecalc'>Balance Calculator</a>
    </li>
    </div>
 <li class='dropdown'><a class='dropbtn'>Lost and Found</a><div 
 class='dropdown-content'>
    <a href='reportyourmissingitem'>Report Your Missing Item</a>
    <a href='reportfounditem'>Report Found Item</a>
    </div>
    </li>
<li><a href='feedback'>Feedback</a></li>
<li><a href='signup'>Sign Up</a></li>
</ul> 

<h1 class='userupdates'> User Updates </h1>
<h2 class='para'> This is the User Updated page. Please use appropriate 
language. Thank you!</h2>


<textarea id='header' type='text' rows='6' cols='100' name='server'>
</textarea>
<input onclick="action(); " type="button" value='Comment'>
<span onload='sol();' id='hello'>

</span>
```

Comment: You really should be a bit more careful. A lot of the HTML isn't properly closed, and you are storing and reading the comments data from two different `localstorage` keys: `commentstorage` and `commentstorag`. Also, what does the `sol()` function do?. At the moment, it is just writing to a variable and never reading from it...

Comment: @Ginkoid yeah the commentstorage thing was meant to be like that i was trying to store either the 'username:comment' and the other one was trying to store the whole span of comments that were entered so that when i refresh the page the comments wouldn't disappear

Comment: @Ginkoid it's purpose is to save the comments that have been entered and put it back when the page refreshes but it's probably wrong but that's the way i thought would work lmap

Comment: Also, `localStorage` is only on the user's local machine, so no one else would be able to view the comments. I am assuming that you eventually will push the comments up to a server, right?